# Are questions about a movie's source considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Specifically, I'd like to know which comic books are comic's movie's plots based on.  I happen to know that the Daredevil movie is based on Daredevil #181, but I'm curious about mostly Marvel movies.  I just want to know if a question like this would be considered on-topic if I asked it.

Answer (score 10):

Asking *if* a movie is based on some pre-existing material and *which* works specifically seems to be a totally viable question. While the question touches upon (and ultimately asks for) external non-movie material, it draws a clear **connection of that material to the actual film** and the answers are (or should be) **about that film**.

So yes, such questions seem to be on-topic (weird exceptional edge-cases notwithstanding) and probably a large portion of the already existing questions tagged [comic-adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comic-adaptation) (or whatever other kinds of adaptations), like [this one about the *Dark Knight* trilogy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/761/49).

Comment: Of course suddenly asking about 20 questions what each specicific MCU movie is based on might come with other problems unrelated to scope issues, like question oversaturation and topic fatigue. But there's ways to mitigate that, too, like asking for broader character arcs spanning multiple films than about each separate individual film or other ways of bringing in some question diversity. But that's largely unrelated to the question of on-topicness and more based on their presentation and their subjective reception within the community.

Comment: So would it be best to space the questions out, or would it be best to ask a "fill in the blanks" question where I list all the movies in the MCU and people can add answers piecemeal?  The latter would probably be best in terms of keeping one question as a reference, but there'd be no way to assign a "checked answer" unless one person knew all the source material.  I'd think this question would be of interest for people, particularly those who want to go back and find copies of the source material to see how true the movie was to its origin.

Comment: It largely depends on what specifically you want to know. Maybe there's a middle-way bettween just asking a question for every single movie and a rather questionable catch-em-all question with a huge CW list answer. Usually there's motifs stretching across multiple films. Or maybe the broad source of a movie is clear to you and you're looking for some specific aspect only. But it really depends on the specific scenario, it's all unrelated to the problem of topicality and more a question of not making the whole thing look uninspired or tiring. Noone will stop you asking 20 such questions. ;-)

Comment: @JohnnyBones as there are currently 17 movies in the MCU, without including the tv and netflix shows and upcoming movies, I don't think having a single question to cover this topic would work, it's too broad imho.

Comment: I'm definitely curious but still can't figure out the best way to pose the question(s).  Movies only, no TV shows.  I just found out that bits of the Venom storyline were dropped, like Peter Parker asked Reed Richards for help analyzing the material (which they obviously couldn't do because of the Marvel/Sony rights issue at the time).  Most of it, however, came from The Amazing Spider-Man #300.